# ngf-max-size $digest() error with ng-file-upload in angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This is source code.

```
<div class="thumbnail" ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-pattern="'*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.gif,*.png'" ngf-max-size="1MB">
```

Below the Derective Html Template.

```
angular.module('ptgui.imagebox',[
    'ngFileUpload'
  ])
  .directive('ptguiImagebox', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'scripts/libs/ptgui/ptgui-imagebox.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        ngModel: "="
      },
      replace: true,
      link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

        $scope.$watch('ngModel',function(newFile, oldFile){
          if (newFile) {
            $scope['ngModel'] = newFile;
          } else {
            $scope['ngModel'] = oldFile;
          }
        });

      }
    };
  }]);
```

Below the directive.

When I upload image over max_size, $digest() error comes up consistently below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00rzR.png)

and I have one more question.
after I find solution that resolve this issue, I will make alert message when someone upload image over max_size.

Thank you your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't change your model inside watch since it creates a loop. If you just need to alert when a file is uploaded whether the size is above you can just check the status.

Let's say you have this input:

```
 <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file"    
         accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="1MB" required
         ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">
```

Then you just need to have this in your html to show the limit size exceeded alert:

```
<i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.maxSize">File too large 
      {{errorFile.size / 1000000|number:1}}MB: max 1M</i>
```

And also you don't need a directive to handle that.

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/) for more info around validation.