# digest error loop comes up when I add ngf-max-size

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I made directive that show image in box.
source is below.

```
angular.module('ptgui.imagebox',[
  'ngFileUpload'
])
  .directive('ptguiImagebox', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'scripts/libs/ptgui/ptgui-imagebox.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        ngModel: "="
      },
      replace: true,
      link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

        //이미지 선택시 취소를 누를경우 리셋되는걸 방지하기 위한 처리
        $scope.$watch('ngModel',function(newFile, oldFile){
          if (newFile) {
            $scope['ngModel'] = newFile;
          } else {
            $scope['ngModel'] = oldFile;
          }
        });

      }
    };
  }]);
```

and below is the directive template.

```
<div class="thumbnail" ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-pattern="'*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.gif,*.png'">
  <img style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" ngf-thumbnail="ngModel || '/assets/images/upload.png'" >
</div>
```

and then I use directive like below.

```
<ptgui-imagebox class="col-md-3" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;" ng-model="product.image" ngf-select></ptgui-imagebox>
                  <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <div class="file-drop-zone" ngf-select ngf-drop ng-model="product.image" ngf-drag-over-class="'file-drop-zone-over'" ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-pattern="'*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.gif,*.png'">
                      <span class="help-block"><i class="fa fa-file-picture-o"> 파일을 여기로 끌어주세요.</i></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

soruce which is above don't use ngf-max-size yet. and that runs I want do.
but I have to check filesize so I add ngf-max-size="1M" like below.

```
<div class="file-drop-zone" ngf-select ngf-drop ng-model="product.image" ngf-drag-over-class="'file-drop-zone-over'" ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-pattern="'*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.gif,*.png'" # ngf-max-size="1MB">
```

but when I add that, I am able to see error which is in loop like below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W8Wj.png)

Comment: Didnt you just asked this question and got an answer?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155650/ngf-max-size-digest-error-with-ng-file-upload-in-angular-js

Comment: Yes I know. but it is not answer i want and I know that solution I found.
so That solution don't help to resolve my issue.

I think I have to change my question.

That directive is making image box with uploading image.
but when I upload image over size, that is into the loop.

what is the problem that directive.
and when does it make loop.

I don't know reason. because I know part of the problem is that directive for imagebox with ngf-max-size.

Thank you your comment.

Comment: so the proper way is to edit/clarify your previous question and comment to the answer, that it didn't help your problem. That way you will not create 10 threads for a single issue with only 1 answer, and provide at least some feedback to people who are trying to help you in their own time, as they will also learn that some solutions are not working in all cases.

Comment: does the upload work, when you have only 1 or 2 files to upload?

Comment: @EddyKim, can you create a plunker with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most probably in here:

```
  $scope.$watch('ngModel',function(newFile, oldFile){
      if (newFile) {
        $scope['ngModel'] = newFile;
      } else {
        $scope['ngModel'] = oldFile;
      }
    });
```

You are overriding your watched variable, removing all the angular internal props from it, causing watch to kick-in again, once the update is done.

You have to correctly handle variable updates:

[Watch variable and change it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322780/watch-variable-and-change-it)

Comment: Thanks your answer. I find solution of my issue.